# PHP DateTime Class Behaving Weirdly

Tags: php, datetime

Consider the following block of code, I've passed a string to the `DateTime` constructor. Now in line 3 I change the contents of the variable i've used, I get an error from line 2?

Why would I get an error from the constructor in line 2 from what I've done in line 3?

I've also tried `clone` on the `$user` object then having one object for the datetime and another for altering its contents. It still doesn't work, gives me the exact same error.

```
$userDatetime = "".$user->user_api_rolling_datetime;

$rollingHourEndsAt = new \DateTime($userDatetime);

$user->user_api_rolling_datetime = new Expression('NOW()');
```

The Error:

`DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (NOW()) at position 3 ((): Unexpected character`

Comment: What's the ``\`` doing there before `DateTime`? And also give `'NOW'` instead of `NOW()`.

Comment: It's to use within the namespace, why would I change line 3 if the issue is with line 2?

Comment: Not sure, but what happens when you use `NOW`?

Comment: Line 3 should have whatever content I wanna put in it. Expression class constructor must have NOW()

Comment: `echo $userDatetime;` before and after line 2, post contents. If `DateTime::__construct` says it's `'NOW()'` it probably is and `NOW()` is indeed not a valid value for the DateTime constructor (although `now` without parenthesis is)

Comment: @ccKep before: 2016-06-04 02:17:19
after: 2016-06-04 02:17:19 

Once line 3 is added, error comes from line 2

Comment: Just did a workaround which somehow fixed it, will post as answer. Though the above code/error makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm unsure what was causing the above issue. The following workaround worked:

```
$rollingHourEndsAt = new \DateTime();
$rollingHourEndsAt->setTimestamp(strtotime($user->user_api_rolling_datetime));
$user->user_api_rolling_datetime = new Expression('NOW()');
```